# ngx-translate: loading i18n json from firebase in ionic3

Tags: ionic3, ngx-translate

In an Ionic3 app what are the ways I could load the language JSON's for ngx-translate? Current approach given on [github](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#aot) mention about keeping JSON files for each language in assets folder. The problem with this approach is that every time I have to add a new language support I have to release a new version of app. Is there a way we could load JSON from Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a new TranslateLoader which would fetch from Firebase. Here is the code:

```
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {TranslateLoader} from "@ngx-translate/core";

export class TranslateFirebaseLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    constructor(public db : AngularFireDatabase) {}

    /**
     * Gets the translations from firebase
     * @param lang
     * @returns {any}
     */
    public getTranslation(lang: string): any {
      return this.db.list('/translations/'+lang)
            .map(data => {
              let fields={};
              data.forEach(field =>{
                fields[field.$key]=field.$value;
              });
              return fields;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a snippet of how you're using this code. I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'getTranslation' of undefined". Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to make it work like this:

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';

// Should work with "AngularFireDatabase" too. But I want it to work offline
import { AngularFireOfflineDatabase } from 'angularfire2-offline/database';

import { TranslateFirebaseLoader } from './TranslateFirebaseLoader';

export function createTranslateLoader(db: AngularFireOfflineDatabase) {
  return new TranslateFirebaseLoader(db, '/my/firebase/path');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [ AngularFireOfflineDatabase ]
      }
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`TranslateFirebaseLoader.ts`

```js
const TranslateFirebaseLoader = (function () {
  function TranslateFirebaseLoader(db, path) {
    this.db = db;
    this.path = path;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the translations from the server
   * @param langCode
   * @returns {any}
   */
  TranslateFirebaseLoader.prototype.getTranslation = function(langCode) {
    return this.db.object(`${this.path}/${langCode}`);
  };

  return TranslateFirebaseLoader;
}());

export { TranslateFirebaseLoader };
```

Obviously, to make it work change the path you're using on Firebase (without the language code in it).
For instance, in this case, the app will try to fetch datas from `/my/firebase/path/en` if the language code "en" is active.